# Concat tuple types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
type T1 = ['a','b','c']
type T2 = ['d','e','f']
type TN = [.., .., ..]

type M = Concat<T1,T2,...,TN> //or Concat<[T1,T2,...,TN]>
//get ['a','b','c','d','e','f',...]

type Error =[...T1,...T2,...T3,...]//A rest element must be last in a tuple type.
```

I want concat many tuple types into one tuple. How to define type `Concat<>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) (TS 4.1.0), you'll be able to:

```
type T1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
type T2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
type TN = [1, 2, 3]

type Concat<T> = T extends [infer A, ...infer Rest]
    ? A extends any[] ? [...A, ...Concat<Rest>] : A
    : T;

type C = Concat<[T1, T2, TN]>; // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 1, 2, 3]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201101#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2gcgIZoDRTQIxzwGM0BdAKFElgCYlU0ATItCVgM3KvGhgDkGKOLlq4AzJR40AwgHsAdsQzAAPDAB8DGFAgAPYBAVMAzqgCWCjhABOUAIK4AdC8vW7AJQgnglKP6gAfgddAyNTKAwFEBQyINQXJ0coRPklFVUvHw04gC4HCgCofJgAbgppaBkGNOU1FHhcGDFYfjINcqA)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [variadic tuple types (TS 4.0)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) instead of adding an additional type abstraction:

```
type T3 = ["g", "h", "i"]

type Concatenated = [...T1, ...T2, ...T3] // ["a", "b", ..., "h", "i"]
```

If there is still need for a separate `Concat` type, following will make use of [TS 4.1 recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) and is more strict than Aleksey's answer:

```
// separate initial and recursive type constructor
type Concat<T extends unknown[][]> = ConcatRec<T>
type ConcatRec<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer I, ...infer R] ?
    I extends unknown[] ? [...I, ...ConcatRec<R>] : never
    : T

type R1 = Concat<[T1, T2, T3]>; // ["a", "b", "c", ... , "i"]
type R2 = Concat<["foo"]>; // now errors properly
```

For example you can combine this type with `Array.prototype.concat`:

```
function concat<T extends [unknown, ...unknown[]][]>(...t: T): Concat<T> {
    return [].concat(...t as any) as any
}

const result = concat([1, "a", 3], [true, 5, new Date()])
// const res: [number, string, number, boolean, number, Date]
```

[Live code sample on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=next#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2gcgIZoDRTQIxzwGM0BdAKFElgCYlU0ATItCVgM3KvGhgGYGKAEQBzYbmEALCVGEBLYZQoB6FVABqGAE7yMTecSjAArmAA20atAAUMXgGViusMCgAWAHQAGAJQ8aAGEAewA7YgxgCFDIiCYhT0T4XETPGFoUpP4yKDVUYQxZYXxZVMkZSUVlPIcIMB1Y414A6BDwyIAeGCgIAA8o0KYAZygTUIBrUOCAd1CUMnmAPgY2iOAAJQhiLsWWqFXIze3uvoHh0Ymp2aWGE-7o85R5UI4IbSgASUzPZ9f39ZyAH4KFBQZ8evdBiMxpMZnMgahUl8oKkDhsth11oscgAuKChCAANzeILBeJgFD2628KzCaw6KHgZEWAG5cuoRIVJCVJMQlFSEMg0QzknRcAJmWy8pyijy5HzvlBKvzrFB1vQhXTOiIOMFgkpWeyetptMFtFTBJr2sAGZKjfNKRwxsRgPIwlBiFqbXcziMUDCrqFvgG4fMFsybKlgOTfHjhTBlgBvUmgvLyAC2FnxEDiI1VGCGQzervdUCYJiswSg+BM8nMwAAtM8oNN5Ew3k1IEMU1BtBBTNpQqgyJ5PdbI4k3AWoBhQiBfDPoZc4Yv9l6dhQAL6UsdDNx9kbIMdrGwoOCSLlQbK4FDAbQV3AAVlwBOmUAAIrEbL4yP48rv9wgIY8RQUITHTfA3lwPddFCUQX3AyDtFwfA9UsWcEIgqCP1iZRd2CSxPHMYJRBsA9fCAA)